# Crash when attempting to assign child pointer to vector of parent pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I've run into a headscratcher, because I'm not getting any errors at compile, just at runtime. Here's some sample code:

### entity.h

```
#ifndef ENTITY_H
#define ENTITY_H

#include <vector>
#include "component.h"

struct Entity
{   
    std::vector<Component*> components;
};

#endif
```

Here's my entity. I just want it to hold a list of data components.

### component.h

```
#ifndef COMPONENT_H
#define COMPONENT_H

#include <string>

struct Component
{
    std::string name;
};

#endif
```

Here's the parent of the components. I need it so that entity can have a list of different kinds of children components.

### comp_position.h

```
#ifndef COMP_POSITION_H
#define COMP_POSITION_H

#include "component.h"

struct Position : Component
{
    Position(int y, int x) {this->y = y; this->x = x; name = "Position";}

    int y, x;
};

#endif
```

Here's a sample of one of the components. Just contains a 2D location of the entity.

### assemblages.h

```
#ifndef ASSEMBLAGES_H
#define ASSEMBLAGES_H

#include "entity.h"
#include "comp_position.h"

Entity* makePlayer(int y, int x){
    Entity* player;
    player->components.push_back(new Position(y, x));
    return player;
}

#endif
```

Here's an assemblage so that I can easily build player type entities. **The moment of putting a Position pointer into the list of Component pointers is where the program crashes.**

### main.cc

```
#include "assemblages.h"
#include "entity.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Entity* player = makePlayer(10, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

And finally here's my main where I just try and create a player. As mentioned above, it is during the assemblage that the program is crashing. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Sorry there are so many files here, I wanted to make sure I was representing my actual program fully while still attempting to strip away as much as I could.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You forget to create player object

   Entity* makePlayer(int y, int x){
      Entity* player  = new Entity;
      player->components.push_back(new Position(y, x));
      return player;
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

`Entity* player;`

Creates an uninitialized `Entity` pointer. It doesn't point to a valid object. You need to initialize it, e.g: by allocating an object on the heap using `new`.

Please note, storing owned objects as bare pointers is not a good practice, it easily leads to memory leaks. Use a `unique_ptr` instead, which will automatically `delete` the pointed object when it goes out of scope.

Comment: This was exactly it. Thank you very much.